# How do I redirect to a page after Contact form is submitted?

Tags: php

All is working fine, except redirect to the thank you page. I can send mail both sides, but after contact form is submitted I can't redirect the page to `thankyou.html` Am I doing something wrong in the code?

```
session_start();
$serverMail = 'example@gmail.com';

$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';
$captcha = isset($_POST['captcha']) ? $_POST['captcha'] : '';
$img_session = isset($_SESSION['img_session']) ? $_SESSION['img_session'] : '';
$website = $_SERVER['mysite'];

$headers = "From: $serverMail\r\n";
$toAdmin = "some example";
$toGuest = "some example";

    if(empty($email) or empty($name) or empty($email) or empty($message)){
        $output = "All fields are required!";
    }
    else{

        //to server side
        if(md5($captcha) == $img_session){
            $mailMessage = "
$name 
some message";

            if (mail($serverMail, $toAdmin, $mailMessage, $headers)) {

            }
        }

        // to guests side
        if(md5($captcha) == $img_session){
            $mailMessage = "
$name 
some message";

            if (mail($email, $toGuest, $mailMessage, $headers)) {
                header('Location:https://stackoverflow.com/');
                exit();
            }
        }
        else{
            $output = "Wrong Captcha Code!";
        }
    }

echo $output;
```

I have to `if(md5($captcha) == $img_session)` because `$mailMessage` are different.

Comment: Why do you have two `if(md5($captcha) == $img_session){` and which one is firing?

Comment: both of them is firing but `$mailMessage` is different @Script47

Comment: **You have an** `exit;` in the first `if(md5($captcha) == $img_session){` if that one gets fired, you never reach the `header()` statement

Comment: `http://helloworld/contact/thankyou.html` is it correct?

Comment: it's correct @devpro

Comment: what is `helloworld` local envirnment? or virtual? or equal to localhost ???

Comment: @devpro it's server

Comment: `helloworld` is it correct domain?

Comment: first and second mail is sending the mailMessage, also I tried header at the first one too it's not redirecting as well

Comment: @devpro it's very correct,

Comment: without TLD? ??

Comment: `exit` **Terminated the script at that line!!!!!** So either this is not the real code, or it does not send Both emails

Comment: it s sending both mails!!!!!! and it's real code. by the way I also tried header at the first mail instead of exit still not redirecting.... @RiggsFolly

Comment: and I deleted exit... still same problem!?

Comment: The ONLY WAY you will reach the second `mail()` statement is if the first `mail()` statement FAILS. Therefore both emails cannot be getting sent

Comment: okay, I deleted exit, and tried that way... still it's not redirecting? Do you see any other problem?  @RiggsFolly

Comment: Are you sure the captcha check is valid?

Comment: yep, actually I can send mails without a problem. the only problem is I can't redirect the page... @Script47

Comment: The code you've posted, Is that **exactly** how it is ? Is there **something else top of that code** ? Is that php file included into another one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code, if it doesnt give try using a different browsers. it may be from the

```
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;url=http://helloworld/contact/thankyou.html">';
```

Comment: it actually, does worked but why the header is not working I really didn't understand.

Comment: in this code "header" , it working, maybe you are calling https and it may not give.
maybe you should only call it thankyou.html, if that page it in a other folder you could use ../thankyou.html.

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
 header("Location: home.php?page=1");
}
require_once 'dbconnect.php';

Comment: actually, the thankyou.html file is in the same folder with index.html I tried to give "header("Location: thankyou.html") etc... but it didn't worked out...

Comment: try testing your code with "echo" to see if it going inside your "If". Or it could be from your captcha, if your using the v3 you will have a timeout of 3 min, and your data will not be able to be send, best chance is changing it to v2, for the user could activate the captcha key.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to test the captcha twice.

Once the captcha is checked, build and send both emails, keeping the status in a temp variable. Once the 2 emails are sent check the status of both and code accordingly for picking up the error whereever it is found.

```
session_start();
$serverMail = 'example@gmail.com';

$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : '';
$captcha = isset($_POST['captcha']) ? $_POST['captcha'] : '';
$img_session = isset($_SESSION['img_session']) ? $_SESSION['img_session'] : '';
$website = $_SERVER['mysite'];

$headers = "From: $serverMail\r\n";
$toAdmin = "some example";
$toGuest = "some example";

if(empty($email) or empty($name) or empty($email) or empty($message)){
    $output = "All fields are required!";
} else{

    if(md5($captcha) == $img_session){

        //to server side
        $mailMessage = "\n$name\n\nsome message";

        $m1 = mail($serverMail, $toAdmin, $mailMessage, $headers)) {

        // to guests side
        $mailMessage = "\n$name\n\nsome other message";

        $m2 = mail($email, $toGuest, $mailMessage, $headers)) {

        if ( $m1 && $m2 ) {
            header('Location:https://stackoverflow.com/');
            exit;
        } else {
            // one or both emails failed to send
            if( ! $m1 ) {
                // error message for server mail failure
            }
            if ( ! $m2 ) {
                // error message for guest mail failure
            }
    } else {
        $output = "Wrong Captcha Code!";
    }
}

echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use "exit" after the first mail!

Comment: that's not true actually, first and second mail is sending the mailMessage, also I tried header at the first one too it's not redirecting as well

Comment: TXT speak is not encouraged on SO. Remember not everybody has English as their first language

Comment: php.net: exit — Output a message and terminate the current script